# Prolog recursion trouble - minimum value in list

Tags: prolog

I have been given a task as follows:

Write a predicate to determine the minimum element in a list. This predicate should not match any value for an
empty list, should work with both positive and negative values and should not introduce an artificial minimum
value.

I have worked through the recursive logic on paper and came up with the following code as a solution. It fails immediately.

```
min_val([H], H).
min_val([H|T], M) :- min_val(T, M1), H =< M1, M is H.
```

If someone could please explain where I have gone wrong, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Prolog doesn't return anything - it simply succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you should ask yourself what if `H > M1`?

Try this instead:

```
min_val([H], H).
min_val([H|T], H) :- min_val(T, M), H < M.
min_val([H|T], M) :- min_val(T, M), H >= M.
```

If you prefer cuts then this is better:

```
min_val([H], H).
min_val([H|T], H) :- min_val(T, M), H < M, !.
min_val([_|T], M) :- min_val(T, M).
```

Comment: Thanks! The version using a cut works. The other version caused Prolog to throw the 'Arguments not sufficiently instantiated' error. I'm not too concerned, as your answer has helped me address the gaps in my logic (and inadvertently help me understand cuts a little more).

Comment: @badger - Both worked fine for me without any errors or warnings. I prefer the first as it is more explicit. I'd like to know what your system complained. SWI worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @badger - Always think when using cuts it is like running with scissors - you have to ask yourself "is this safe?" If it is then fine, but otherwise they should be used judiciously.

Comment: Never mind, I left the anonymous variable in place when switching between the two. It works fine... my bad! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
% our public predicate 'min/2'
min( [X|Xs], M ) :- min(Xs,X,M).

% min/3 does the actual work via tail recursion
min( [] , M , M ).
min( [X|Xs], T, M ) :- min_val(X,T,T1), min(Xs,T1,M).

% min_val/3 determines the lesser of two value.
min_val( X, Y, X ) :- X <  Y.
min_Val( X, Y, Y ) :- X >= Y.
```

Comment: Fixed code typos. One issue with the code remains: the `min_val/3` goal creates a choice-point when `X <  Y`. This means that the space complexity of the `min/3` predicate is **not** O(1) as suggested by looking only to its tail recursive definition. Can be solved by adding a cut to the first clause of `min_val/3`.